# Rsync --backup-dir and --copy-dest options

Tags: rsync

server1 has a **filename.tgz** and I need to copy it to server2. I would like to keep daily copies on server2, like:

```
/backup/Mon/filename.tgz
/backup/Tue/filename.tgz
...
/backup/Sun/filename.tgz
```

I have been reading the rsync man page, but I'm not clear on whether I should use the **--backup-dir** option or the **--copy-dest** option

I'll have a command similar to

```
rsync -av --copy-dir=../`date -d yesterday +%a` filename.tgz dest:/backup/`date +%a`/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overthinking it. rsync will automatically create directories, so you can just do:

> rsync -v filename.tgz server2:/backup/`date -d yesterday +%a`/

Make sure you have the trailing slash, or the backup file will be called the day of the week instead.